# How to set CATALINA_HOME variable in windows 7?

Tags: java, tomcat, environment-variables, java-home, catalina

I have downloaded `apache-tomcat-7.0.35`. My JDK version is `jdk1.6.0_27`.

How do I configure `CATALINA_HOME` as an environment variable and how do I run Tomcat server under Windows 7?

Answer (score 80):

Setting the `JAVA_HOME`, `CATALINA_HOME` Environment Variable on Windows

One can do using command prompt:

1. `set JAVA_HOME=C:\ "top level directory of your java install"`
2. `set CATALINA_HOME=C:\ "top level directory of your Tomcat install"`
3. `set PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin`

OR you can do the same:

1. Go to system properties
2. Go to environment variables and add a new variable with the name `JAVA_HOME` and provide variable value as `C:\ "top level directory of your java install"`
3. Go to environment variables and add a new variable with the name  `CATALINA_HOME` and provide variable value as `C:\ "top level directory of your Tomcat install"`
4. In path variable add a new variable value as `;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;`

Comment: On Win10, you can also press Windows key and enter `Edit environment variables for your account` (works on non-admin accounts too)

Answer (score 15):

Assuming Java (JDK + JRE) is installed in your system, do the following steps:

1. Install Tomcat7
2. Copy 'tools.jar' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\lib' and paste it under 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib'.
3. Setup paths in your Environment Variables as shown below:

**C:>echo %path%**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;
```

**C:>echo %classpath%**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\lib\tools.jar;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib\servlet-api.jar;
```

**C:>echo %CATALINA_HOME%**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0;
```

**C:>echo %JAVA_HOME%**

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27;
```

Now you can test whether Tomcat is setup correctly, by typing the following commands in your command prompt:

```
C:/>javap javax.servlet.ServletException
C:/>javap javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
```

It should show a bunch of classes

Now start Tomcat service by double clicking on '**Tomcat7.exe**' under 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\bin'.

Answer (score 5):

[Here](https://yellow-jbox.blogspot.cz/2011/04/how-to-set-catalinahomepath-variables.html) is tutorial how to do that (CATALINA_HOME is path to your Tomcat, so I suppose something like `C:/Program Files/Tomcat/`. And for starting server, you need to execute script `startup.bat` from command line, this will make it:)

Comment: "Here" link is not working. Also the suggested edit queue is full.

Answer (score 2):

In order to set CATALINA_HOME:

1. First, unzip and paste the apache-tomcat-7.1.100 folder in your C:// drive folder.

**NOTE:** Do not place your apache tomcat folder within any other folder or drive, place it directly in C:// drive folder only. (I did this mistake and none of the above-mentioned solutions were working).

2. Open *environment variable* dialog box (windows key+ pause-break key --> advanced setting).
3. Add a new *variable name* as "**CATALINA_HOME**" and add the *variable path* as "**C://apache-tomcat-7.1.100**"(as in my case), in ***System Variables***.
4. Edit **PATH** variable name add "**%CATALINA_HOME%\bin**" and press OK.
5. Close the window and it will be saved.
6. Open **Command Prompt** window and type command- "**%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat**" to run and start the Tomcat server.
7. END!

Comment: upvoting for environment variable dialog box shortcut

Answer (score 1):

There is no requirement of setting CATALINA-HOME.

Follow below instruction .

Right click on computer --> properties --> Advanced system setting --> Environment variables.

User variables section --> click on "New" --> variable name : CLASSPATH , variable value : D:\java\lib*.;D:\tomcat8\lib\servlet-api.jar.; --> Click "Ok"

New --> variable name : PATH , variable value : D:\java\bin; --> Click "Ok"

System variables section:-

Click on "New" --> variable name : PATH , variable value :  D:\java\jre --> Click "Ok"

I've installed java and tomcat in D drive henceforth the locations above are under my respective paths.

Give location paths where java and tomcat are installed in your PC. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Java (JDK + JRE) is installed in your system, do the following:

1. Install Tomcat7
2. Copy 'tools.jar' from 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\lib' and pasted it under 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\lib'.
3. Setup paths in your Environment Variables as shown below:

C:/>javap javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

It should show a bunch of classes