# Tomcat not starting JRE not defined correctly

Tags: java, tomcat

[image]

i have set all env variables but still as U see in window Im not able to start
Apachy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the semicolon characters from the end of JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME. You also only need to set one of these.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the given steps through below link. May u have missed any steps

[How to set CATALINA_HOME variable in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14579661/how-to-set-catalina-home-variable-in-windows-7)

may it will help you

Comment: It is not necessary to set CATALINA_HOME when starting Tomcat with the standard scripts.

Comment: @Mark thanks for your attention toward my answer can you  please provide some useful notes and advice toward standard scripts.